# How do I display an ascii art string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ascii

I'm trying to use an ascii art string that I made with [artii](https://github.com/miketierney/artii) in a ruby program. The string can be generated using the cli as expected:

[image]

However when I try to save it as a string and either `puts`, `p`, or `print` it, it doesn't work. I thought it might be because the slashes need to be escaped which I've tried to do, but it looks like I'm not gsubing correctly either. How would I go about going from a working string on the cli to a working string in a ruby program that's printing the string to stdout?
[image]

```
banner = "
  _____       _             _   _       _       
 |  __ \     | |           | \ | |     | |      
 | |__) |   _| |__  _   _  |  \| | ___ | |_ ___ 
 |  _  / | | | '_ \| | | | | . ` |/ _ \| __/ _ \
 | | \ \ |_| | |_) | |_| | | |\  | (_) | |_  __/
 |_|  \_\__,_|_.__/ \__, | |_| \_|\___/ \__\___|
                     __/ |                      
                    |___/                       

"
print banner
print banner.gsub(/\\/, "\\\\")
puts "One slash: \\"
puts "Two slashes: \\\\"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `gsub` backslashes because they're not there: you're trying to unspill the milk. The syntax `"foo\ bar"` will produce the string `"foo bar"`, exactly like if the backslash wasn't there. It's not that the backslash is not displaying - it is never in the string in the first place, so there is nothing to `gsub`. You have basically two solutions: either double the backslashes in your literal by hand or by editor replacement (`"foo\\ bar"`) *before* your program executes:

```
artii 'Ruby Note' | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
```

or read the string in from somewhere so it is not interpreted by Ruby syntax:

```
banner = File.read(DATA)
puts banner
__END__
  _____       _             _   _       _       
 |  __ \     | |           | \ | |     | |      
 | |__) |   _| |__  _   _  |  \| | ___ | |_ ___ 
 |  _  / | | | '_ \| | | | | . ` |/ _ \| __/ _ \
 | | \ \ |_| | |_) | |_| | | |\  | (_) | |_  __/
 |_|  \_\__,_|_.__/ \__, | |_| \_|\___/ \__\___|
                     __/ |                      
                    |___/
```

will display what you want.

Comment: right on thanks Amadan! I used your first suggestion and it totally worked. Just a heads up I think your backtick and the end needs to be a single quote :)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use a [heredoc that disables interpolation and escaping](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents):

```
puts <<-'EOF'
 _____       _             _   _       _       
|  __ \     | |           | \ | |     | |      
| |__) |   _| |__  _   _  |  \| | ___ | |_ ___ 
|  _  / | | | '_ \| | | | | . ` |/ _ \| __/ _ \
| | \ \ |_| | |_) | |_| | | |\  | (_) | |_  __/
|_|  \_\__,_|_.__/ \__, | |_| \_|\___/ \__\___|
                    __/ |                      
                   |___/                       
EOF
```